# Setting object value off class included via template include WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom plugin for a wordpress website.
The wp-content/my-plugin/index.php contains multiple includes of files.

Example:

```
include('lib/WhiseApiSeo.php'); // this is the WhiseApiSeo class
```

When a visitor opens the website and the query_var estatePurpose is used index.php also includes a view_estates.php page as below

```
if ( get_query_var( 'estatePurpose' )  ) {
        add_filter('template_include', function () {
            return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'view_estates.php';
        });
    }
```

Via the the WhiseApiSeo.php code I made a setter for the meta title and meta description.

```
<?php
    class WhiseApiSeo {

    public $headTitle;
    public $headDescription;


    function __construct()
    {



    }

    public function setHeadTitle($Value)
    {
    $this->headTitle = $Value;
    }


    public function setHeadDescription($Value)
    {
    $this->headDescription = $Value;
    }


    public function setMetaTags()
    {

        function set_page_title()
        {
            return $this->headTitle;
        }

        add_filter('wp_title', 'set_page_title');

        function set_page_desc()
        {
            return $this->headDescription;
        }

        add_filter('wp_metadesc', 'set_page_desc');

    }
```

}
?>

The view_estates.php contains all the code for displaying the estates content.
In the view_estates.php file I call the WhiseApiSeo class as follow:

```
$objectWhiseApiSeo = new WhiseApiSeo();
$objectWhiseApiSeo->setHeadTitle('Test Title');
$objectWhiseApiSeo->setHeadDescription('Test description');
$objectWhiseApiSeo->setMetaTags();
echo $objectWhiseApiSeo->headTitle;
echo $objectWhiseApiSeo->headDescription;
```

It seems like view_estates.php which is loaded via the Wordpress add_filter function, is not setting the title and description or am I doing something totally wrong?
There is no content displaying when I echo the title and description.

Love to hear from you.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are seperating this in two setter functions and then combine the call of both in one function? Why are you not using return right away?  Another thing to look at: `add_filter` will only have an effect if `apply_filters`  being called having that argument. So maybe the filter is not getting applied.

Comment: _"There is no content displaying when I echo the title and description."_ - that part should work fine, see https://3v4l.org/BCQVu The issue here is more likely _when_ this executes. Your `setMetaTags` method tries to add filters for title and meta description, and I am guessing that happens after the point when these filters get applied here.

Comment: I tried to add some code to view_estates.php so the setMetaTags function is called when  the setup theme is ready. Still not working. 

`$objectWhiseApiSeo = new WhiseApiSeo();
function wp_add_seo() {
    $objectWhiseApiSeo->setMetaTags('Aanbod - VR Makelaars', 'test');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wp_add_seo' );`